# Angular 7 redirect application page to index.html

Tags: angular2-routing, angular7, angular7-router

Is it possible to redirect to **index.html** page from any other module page in an application using angular 7?

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is not the "Angular way" to do it, but it is works.

Create a new typescript file (e.g. locationUtils.ts) and add this function to it

```
export function goToIndexPage(){
  let index = ""; //location of your index page
  window.location.href = window.location.origin + window.location.pathName + index;
}
```

Then just use it from anywhere

In addition, you should take care about # sign in your path if you are using it